# LR(1) parse straight to Abstract syntax tree

Tags: java, parsing, tree, abstract-syntax-tree, lr-grammar

So I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445511/how-do-i-translate-lr1-parse-into-a-abstract-syntax-tree) close this recently and received an very good answer. However the steps that were described seemed more like the steps to create a concrete syntax tree.

> Each reduction in the LR parsing process corresponds to an internal
>   node in the parse tree. The rule being reduced is the internal AST
>   node, and the items popped off the stack correspond to the children of
>   that internal node. The item pushed for the goto corresponds to the
>   internal node, while those pushed by shift actions correspond to
>   leaves (tokens) of the AST.
>
> Putting all that together, you can easily build an AST by createing a
>   new internal node every time you do a reduction and wiring everything
>   together appropriately.
>   ~Chris Dodd

I know that the parse tree is implied by the steps taken however I don't want to explicitly build the parse tree. And generating a node every reduction seems like it would result in the entire parse tree. I have considered that I only build a node if a certain state is seen.  However this seems like it would not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build a node on *every* reduction, and the nodes you do build don't need to include *every* symbol being reduced. Nor do the reduced symbols need to appear in the same order as the parse.

In many cases, an AST is a simplification of the full parse tree, corresponding to the above.

Simple example, for an expression grammar, using a yacc-like parser generator:

```
expr: term            { $$ = $1; /* see below */ }
    | expr '+' term   { $$ = new_sum_node($1, $3); }
term: factor          { $$ = $1; /* see below */ }
    | term '*' factor { $$ = new_product_node($1, $3); }
factor: '(' expr ')'  { $$ = $2; /* See below */ }
      | ID            { $$ = new_variable_node($1); }
      | NUMBER        { $$ = new_literal_node($1); }
```

The AST is built as the semantic value of the non-terminals. The functions `new_*_node` are expected to return a newly-allocated node of the indicated type. (Here we assume that there is some mechanism to deduce from a pointer what type of node it is. For example, it would be possible to use subtyping and virtual functions.)

In Yacc (and similar parser generators), every symbol (terminal or non-terminal) has an associated "value", and every production has an associated action which executes when the production is reduced. The action for a production can assign the "value" of the non-terminal being reduced. The action can make use of the "values" of the components of the right-hand-side, since each one is either a terminal (whose value was set by the scanner) or a non-terminal which has already been reduced. In effect, this is an [S-attributed grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-attributed_grammar).

Some of the above reductions do not appear at all in the AST. In particular, the unit reductions (`expr:term` and `term:factor`) simply pass through the AST for the right-hand side. Similarly, the parenthesis reduction `term:'(' expr ')'` simply passes through the AST for the `expr`, with the result that the parentheses effectively vanish from the AST. (That's not correct in all languages; in some languages, apparently-redundant parentheses actually affect the semantics and you'd need to create an AST node to record the fact.)

In Yacc, `$$ = $1` is the default reduction action if no action is specified, and since most unit reductions are eliminated from the AST, they will normally be shown without reduction actions. I made them explicit for didactic purposes; in practice, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you to elaborate on pass through and default action. Also I am not familiar with the $$ notation. Is this just representing a variable? Sorry if that's a dumb question, for some reason my mind is just having a hard time with this particular problem. But thank you for you reply!

Comment: @devin: sorry, i was assuming a yacc-like parser generator, i should have been more explicit. In yacc, setting $$ sets the "value" of the reduced nonterminal. The "value"s of the right-hand side symbols are $1, $2, etc.

Comment: @DevinWall: Hope that additional explanation helps somewhat.

Comment: Alright thank you. And it should. I have actually been taking the hard way i wrote my own LR(1) table generator and parser framework.